# How to add new services to a store in Mega Mall Story?

Tags: ios, mega-mall-story

I have played this game through once, and noticed that I often struggled with being able to add new services to shops. They often said "Hard" or "Very Hard", and I know that in other Kairosoft games, you can trigger different things to make this type of thing easier. Is there a way to make adding services easier, so I don't keep wasting hearts trying to do it over and over again?

Comment: I don't believe it would be possible to trigger it manually.

Comment: Trigger what manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your store increases in level the difficulty goes down.

Also, sometimes if the store has been in operation long enough it will prompt you to add a new service for 1 heart. But I have no idea how to trigger that condition manually.